# Can a Log4perl filter access the Mapped Diagnostic Context?

Tags: perl, log4perl

I'm writting some Perl CGI scripts, and am using [Log4perl](http://p3rl.org/Log%3a%3aLog4perl) to log to various files. I thought it may be useful to be able to trace a particular (or various) user's activities to a separate log file. I can put a hook into my session routine to stuff the userid into the [MDC](http://p3rl.org/Log%3a%3aLog4perl#Mapped-Diagnostic-Context-MDC-), but I don't know of any way to access the MDC from a [filter](http://p3rl.org/Log%3a%3aLog4perl#Custom-Filters). As far as I know, the MDC is only used for pattern creation.

Is this doable with Log4perl?

Per suggestion below I added a filter in my config file, but it's still not working:

```
log4perl.appender.User           = Log::Log4perl::Appender::File
log4perl.appender.User.filename  = /data/wwwwii/logs/appUser.log
log4perl.appender.User.syswrite  = 1
log4perl.appender.User.Filter    = User
log4perl.appender.User.layout    = PatternLayout
log4perl.appender.User.layout.ConversionPattern=%p{1} %d{ISO8601}Z [%03r] %15X{remoteAddr}/%05P %M %L  --> %m%n

log4perl.filter.User = sub { Log::Log4perl::MDC->get('userId') == 12; }
```

I stuff the userid as soon as I do the session lookup, but I never do get an appUser.log file created. No errors show up that I can see.

Comment: Sorry... [link](http://search.cpan.org/~mschilli/Log-Log4perl-1.34/lib/Log/Log4perl.pm#Mapped_Diagnostic_Context_(MDC))

Comment: Never mind, I wasn't calling the appender in the first place. All is well now, apologies for the confusion!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can't you just do:

```
my $value   = Log::Log4perl::MDC->get($key);   # for 1 value, or
my $hashref = Log::Log4perl::MDC->get_context; # for the whole context
```

Comment: My question was vague after a day immersed in perl cgi. I usually wait for a day and take a fresh look before posting questions but didn't follow my own advice this time.